# How to show 3 random divs on 3 random places

Tags: php

How to show 3 random divs on 3 random places
I have 6 potentionaly places for divs.
All 6 divs need to be hidden for now. 
When page load I need to show only 3 random divs, and another 3 divs need to be hidden.

```
<?php

$divs = array('<div id="divFirst">First Div</div>','<div id="divFirst">Second Div</div>','<div id="divFirst">Third Div</div>');

// Array with 3 random keys from $divs
$randKeys = array_rand($divs, 2);

//echo $divs[$randKeys[0]]; // First random div
//echo $divs[$randKeys[1]]; // Second random div
//echo $divs[$randKeys[2]]; // 3rd div
//shuffle($divs);
?>


<div class="text">This is a simple text</div>
<?php echo $divs[$randKeys[0]]; ?>
<div class="text">This is a simple text</div>
<?php echo $divs[$randKeys[1]]; ?>
<div class="text">This is a simple text</div>
<?php echo $divs[$randKeys[2]]; ?>
<div class="text">This is a simple text</div>
<?php echo $divs[$randKeys[1]]; ?>
<div class="text">This is a simple text</div>
<?php echo $divs[$randKeys[0]]; ?>
<div class="text">This is a simple text</div>
<?php echo $divs[$randKeys[2]]; ?>
```

Comment: you seem to be doing more or less what you ask, whats the specific help you need?

Comment: It's hard to tell what help you are looking for. What are you expecting to happen with your code and what happens instead. BTW, your div id values are all the same, html elements should really have a unique id.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: `$randKeys = array_rand($divs, 2);`

The second parameter specifies the number of items you want out of the array.  You want 3, but you told it you want 2.

Then you're doing `<?php echo $divs[$randKeys[2]]; ?>` That is, trying to print the third element from the array (i.e. arrays start counting at 0).  But you only have 2 elements in the array now.

Also, it would make more sense to only keep the **contents** of the divs in your array. Then you can do like:

```
$randKeys = array_rand($divs, 6);
//because you want 3 shown, 3 hidden, thus 6

for($i=0; $i<6; $i++)
{
   $style='display: block';
   if($i>=3)
   {
      //we hide the last 3
      $style='display: none';
   }
   echo "<div id='div_$i' style='$style'>" . $divs[$randKeys[$i]] . "</div>";
}
```

That solves the problem mentioned in the comments about your div ids not being unique.

However, in order to pick 6, you need to actually have 6 elements in the `$divs` array because the [docs for array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) state:

> Trying to pick more elements than there are in the array will result in an E_WARNING level error, and NULL will be returned.

Comment: Yes, this look like a solution. But how echo this?
What I call instead `<?php echo $divs[$randKeys[0]]; ?>` ?